# What does the ## macro operator do in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, macros

I got very confused when my *C++* book said, if I have five functions named `fOnePrint`, `ftwoprint`, `fthreeprint`, `fourprint`, and `fFivePrint`, and you need to declare them using the `##`,
you do:

```
#define fPrint(x) f##x## print
```

Can someone please explain to me how to use this `##` concatenation macro with simple example?

I am using MS Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: Dont you google the same??

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example:

```
#define XY(x,y) x##y
```

which translates

`XY(1,2)` to `12`.

Similarly,

```
#define fprint(S) f##S##print
```

would translate

`fprint(One)` to `fOnePrint`
`fprint(Two)` to `fTwoPrint` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There's no compulsion to use the `##` operator.  However, the intent is that you can if you wish, by writing, for example:

```
fPrint(two)("format string %d\n", value);
```

which looks kinda funny.  However, the `fPrint(two)` macro expands to

```
ftwoprint
```

and then the following parentheses might make the code into a valid call to the function.  There is nothing to stop you writing this instead:

```
ftwoprint("format string %d\n", value);
```

It is far from clear there's a notational benefit to the macro.